# How to output datocms graphql query with an array inside multiple posts

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I am using the DatoCMS portfolio gatsby cloud autogenerated template. I have been able to successfully change some models in DataCMS that reflect in my graphQL playground, I then can adjust my code to reflect those changes. Now this model is for posts so there is multiples of them, now the part I am getting stuck on is, I have added a modular component to each post, which creates an array in the graphQL returned data, and I can't for the life of me figure out how to map thorough it when I am already mapping through all the posts that it is contained in.

Here is my code, and I am trying to output the data from `details.task`

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link, graphql } from 'gatsby'
import Masonry from 'react-masonry-component'
import Img from 'gatsby-image'
import Layout from "../components/layout"

const IndexPage = ({ data }) => (
  <Layout>
    {/* <Masonry className="showcase"> */}
      {data.allDatoCmsPricing.edges.map(({ node: pricing }) => (
        <div key={pricing.id} className="">
          <figure className="card">
            {/* <Link to={`/works/${work.slug}`} className="card__image">
              <Img fluid={work.coverImage.fluid} />
            </Link> */}
              <h6 className="card__title">
                <Link to={`/works/${pricing.slug}`}>{pricing.title}</Link>
              </h6>
              <div className="card__description">
                <p>{pricing.excerpt}</p>
              </div>
              {{pricing.details.task}}//Tasks go here, I know this wont work
          </figure>
        </div>
      ))}
    {/* </Masonry> */}
  </Layout>
)

export default IndexPage

export const query = graphql`
  query IndexQuery {
    allDatoCmsPricing(sort: { fields: [position], order: ASC }) {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          title
          slug
          excerpt
          details{
            task
          }
          coverImage {
            fluid(maxWidth: 450, imgixParams: { fm: "jpg", auto: "compress" }) {
              ...GatsbyDatoCmsSizes
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

and here is the resulting data from a playground query

```
{
  "data": {
    "allDatoCmsPricing": {
      "edges": [
        {
          "node": {
            "id": "DatoCmsPricing-1913799-en",
            "title": "Silver",
            "slug": "flyer-1",
            "excerpt": "European minnow priapumfish mosshead warbonnet shrimpfish bigscale. Cutlassfish porbeagle shark ricefish walking catfish glassfish Black swallower.",
            "details": [
              {
                "task": "Client Consultation"
              },
              {
                "task": "S.M.A.R.T Goal Setting"
              },
              {
                "task": "Fitness Assessment"
              },
              {
                "task": "Client Centered Exercises"
              },
              {
                "task": "1-2 Sessions per week"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "id": "DatoCmsPricing-1913807-en",
            "title": "Packaging 1",
            "slug": "packaging-1",
            "excerpt": "Efficiently unleash cross-media information without cross-media value. Quickly maximize timely deliverables for real-time schemas. Dramatically maintain clicks-and-mortar.",
            "details": []
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "id": "DatoCmsPricing-1913806-en",
            "title": "Stationery 1",
            "slug": "stationery-1",
            "excerpt": "User experience deployment MVP ecosystem direct mailing. Creative iteration early adopters research & development partnership buyer investor innovator success scrum project validation graphical user interface termsheet mass market.",
            "details": []
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from another source the following is what I was looking for to output the tasks

```
<ul className="details-list">{pricing.details.map(detailEntry => { 

  return <li key={detailEntry.id}><span>{detailEntry.task}</span></li>

 })}</ul>
```